# How to run functions synchornisly in one Click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use ReacJs and Redux in my project and have a sitoation where i need to click only one time and function have to run 2 inside functions step by step. 2nd function cant run before ended func2. How can I do this function only in one click on mainfunc()? Need a example code please.

```
func1()

func2()

mainfunc(){
 func1()
 func2()
}
```

Comment: is function1 synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: it is syncronous.

Comment: to run 2nd func need a click 2 times on mainfunc(), because after first click need to finish 1st func and cant run second together.

Comment: if it' syncronous then they will be executed one after another by default, no need to do anything.
if you are updating states in those functions and calling on resolving a promise you may need to look into this https://blog.logrocket.com/simplifying-state-management-in-react-apps-with-batched-updates/

Comment: ^^ kinda yeah, but the problem I think OP is having is around both funcs are fired at the same time and one relies on the other. The code doesn't care to wait for one to finish before moving onto the next it just sees "are there are two functions, let's call them both" leading to the data being out of sync between the two. 
This not an ideal way of writing code and OP should really just refactor to async await however if it's out of their control then React has a bunch of hooks that can help get around this issue. This issue is common with newer devs but everything is a learning opportunity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a many options in React to achieve a goal, there is no one way to do something.

Here are a couple of example:

1. using async events (API calls, promises etc...)

```js
// async 
export const MyComponent = () => {

  const eventOne = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      resolve(true);
    })
  }

  const eventTwo = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      resolve(true);
    })
  }

  const handleClick = async () => {
    await eventOne();
    await eventTwo();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  )
};
```

So Here we are just taking two async events and waiting for each one to finish before moving onto the next using async/await.

Another approach might be to utilise state , in which case you could do something like this:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// state 
export const MyComponent = () => {

  const [eventOneHasHappened, setEventOneHasHappened] = useState(false);

  const triggerEventOne = () => {
    // do something

    setEventOneHasHappened(true);
  }

  const triggerEventTwo = () => {
    // do something
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (eventOneHasHappened) {
      triggerEventTwo();
    }
  }, [eventOneHasHappened]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    triggerEventOne();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  )
};
```

There are many more ways to do something like this depending if your using async or not but try to get used to React hooks, they're very useful